# ATtiny 402 timer 0 is providing unexpected interrupt period

Tags: c, avr

I am using an ATtiny 402 to implement a timer interrupt. The internal clock I have selected is 20Mhz. Prescaler is not enabled. For timer interrupt, I am using timer 0 in normal mode. The PA6 is used as an output to see the Interrupt time period by an oscilloscope.

And for the experiment, I used the TOP value of 30000.

In the current configuration, the Timer interrupt time should be  = TOP * (Pre  / Clk) = 30000 * ( 1 / 20000000) s = 1.5 ms

But in the oscilloscope, the interrupt period time is: 8.8 ms

Am is miscalculating something or is there any mistake in my code.

My source code is   :

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>

FUSES = {
    .WDTCFG = 0x00, // WDTCFG {PERIOD=OFF, WINDOW=OFF}
    .BODCFG = 0x00, // BODCFG {SLEEP=DIS, ACTIVE=DIS, SAMPFREQ=1KHz, LVL=BODLEVEL0}
    .OSCCFG = 0x02, // OSCCFG {FREQSEL=20MHZ, OSCLOCK=CLEAR}
    .TCD0CFG = 0x00, // TCD0CFG {CMPA=CLEAR, CMPB=CLEAR, CMPC=CLEAR, CMPD=CLEAR, CMPAEN=CLEAR, CMPBEN=CLEAR, CMPCEN=CLEAR, CMPDEN=CLEAR}
    .SYSCFG0 = 0xC4, // SYSCFG0 {EESAVE=CLEAR, RSTPINCFG=UPDI, CRCSRC=NOCRC}
    .SYSCFG1 = 0x07, // SYSCFG1 {SUT=64MS}
    .APPEND = 0x00, // APPEND {APPEND=User range:  0x0 - 0xFF}
    .BOOTEND = 0x00, // BOOTEND {BOOTEND=User range:  0x0 - 0xFF}
};

LOCKBITS = 0xC5; // {LB=NOLOCK}


void io_set(void){
    PORTA.DIR = 0b01000000 ;   // pin PA1 input others output
    PORTA.PIN1CTRL = 0b0001000  ;  // pullup PA1 
}

void clk_conf(void){
    CLKCTRL.MCLKCTRLA = 0b00000000 ;  // internal clock 20 Mhz ////
    CLKCTRL.MCLKCTRLB = 0b00000000 ;  // Prescaler is not enabled /////
}

void timer0_init(){
    TCA0.SINGLE.CTRLA = 0b00000001 ;// // Peripheral enable, clock = CLOCK_PER
    TCA0.SINGLE.CTRLB = 0b00000000 ;// // Timer in normal mode
    TCA0.SINGLE.PER    = 30000;    ////// Setting the Top value to 30000
    TCA0.SINGLE.INTCTRL = 0b00000001; //
}

void en_global_int(){
    SREG |= 0b10000000 ; //enable global interrupt
}

int main(void)
{
    clk_conf() ; 
    io_set() ; 
    en_global_int() ; 
    timer0_init() ;
    sei()  ; 
    while (1){

    }
}


ISR(TCA0_OVF_vect){
    TCA0.SINGLE.INTFLAGS = TCA_SINGLE_OVF_bm; //clearing the flag
    TCA0.SINGLE.CNT = 0 ; //counter set to zero
    
    PORTA.OUT ^= 0b01000000 ; //toggling the output pin 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default after reset, the CLOCK_MAIN is set to 20MHz and CLOCK_PER is set to 20/6=3.33333MHz with a prescaler of 6, that's exactly what you are using.

The reason your attempt of setting the main clock prescaler didn't work is because system critical I/O register settings are protected from accidental modification by Configuration Change Protection (CCP). Read section 10 of [Attiny202/402 datasheet](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/ATtiny202-402-AVR-MCU-with-Core-Independent-Peripherals_and-picoPower-40001969A.pdf) and section 8.5.7 about CCP, and then section 3.5 on how to write to CCP on [Getting Started with Writing C-Code for AVR® MCUs](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/Appnotes/AVR1000b-Getting-Started-Writing-C-Code-for-AVR-DS90003262B.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

In a project (with ATTiny406) i had the same problems. I solved it with a few lines:

```c
// CLOCK Setup
CCP = CCP_IOREG_gc;
CLKCTRL.MCLKCTRLA = CLKCTRL_CLKSEL_OSC20M_gc;
while(!(CLKCTRL.MCLKSTATUS & CLKCTRL_OSC20MS_bm));

CCP = CCP_IOREG_gc;
CLKCTRL.MCLKCTRLB = 0x00;
CLKCTRL.OSC20MCTRLA = CLKCTRL_RUNSTDBY_bm;
```

Maybe this helps...

Comment: By using _PROTECTED_WRITE(regAddress, regValue) my problem got solved.